# UFS - how a 0 bytes file broke filesystem header?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, corruption, partition, fsck

**For those reaching here; Unfortunately I could not recover the data, after various tries and reproducing the problem it was too costy to keep trying, so we just used a past backup to recreate the information needed**

A human error broke an 150G UFS filesystem (Solaris).

When trying to do a backup of the filesytem (c0t0d0s3) the ufsdump(1M) hasn't been correctly used.
I will explain the background that led to this ...

The admin used:

```
# ufsdump 0f /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 > output_1
root@ats-br000432 # ufsdump 0f /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 > output_1
Usage: ufsdump [0123456789fustdWwnNDCcbavloS [argument]] filesystem
```

This is a bad usage, so it created a file called output_1 with 0 bytes:

```
# ls -la output_1
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root         0 abr 12 14:12 output_1
```

Then, the syntax used was:

```
# ufsdump 0f /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3 output_1
```

Which wrote that 0 bytes file *output_1* to ***/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3*** - which was the partition slice

Now, interestingly, due to being a 0 bytes file, we thought that this would cause no harm to the filesystem, but it did.
When trying to ls in the mountpoint, the partition claimed there was an I/O error, when umounting and mounting again, the filesystem showed no contents, but the disk space was still showing as used just like it was previously.

I assume, at some point, the filesystem 'header' was affected, right? Or was it the slice information?

A small fsck try brings up this:

```
** /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3
** Last Mounted on /database
** Phase 1 - Check Blocks and Sizes
INCORRECT DISK BLOCK COUNT I=11 (400 should be 208)
CORRECT?
```

> Disk block count / I=11

- this seems that the command broke filesystem information regarding its own contents, right?
  When we tried to **fsck -y -F ufs /dev/dsk..** various files have been recovered, but not the dbf files we are after (which are GB sized)

What can be done now? Should I try every superblock information from newfs -N ?

**EDIT**: new information regarding partition
newfs output showing superblock information

```
# newfs -N /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3
Warning: 2826 sector(s) in last cylinder unallocated
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3:     265104630 sectors in 43149 cylinders of 48 tracks, 128 sectors
        129445,6MB in 2697 cyl groups (16 c/g, 48,00MB/g, 5824 i/g)
super-block backups (for fsck -F ufs -o b=#) at:
 98464, 196896, 295328, 393760, 492192, 590624, 689056, 787488, 885920,
Initializing cylinder groups:
.....................................................
super-block backups for last 10 cylinder groups at:
 264150944, 264241184, 264339616, 264438048, 264536480, 264634912, 264733344,
 264831776, 264930208, 265028640
```

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you believed the 0-byte file *was* your backup?

Comment: When using ufsdump, the argument was wrong, the output_1 file was supposed to be a file generated by ufsdump dump, so yes, it was supposed to be a backup from ufsdump

Comment: Try `fsck -F ufs -o b=98464 /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3`. **Do not answer yes to any question unless you're willing to potentially lose some files.** If you can't afford to lose files, use `dd` to copy the filesystem to another drive and run `fsck` on that drive instead. Since you already ran `fsck -y`, though, it's likely that all the alternate superblocks have been updated by `fsck`.

Comment: If you just need a few files, try running [ff](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/ff-1m.html#scrolltoc) to see if the files are visible in what is left of the directory structure.

Comment: I duplicated the problem under Solaris 11 using a UFS file system built on a ramdisk.  The bad news is I was unable to recover any files from the file system no matter which superblock I used for the post-corruption `fsck`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I backed up everything before fsck'ng, have tried various `fsck -F ufs -o b=X` - what's the idea to avoid `y` to all, how should I know which fsck questions I should ignore? I also ran `ff` on a copy of the drive for two hours and got no output, but I'm bringing up a Solaris lab with SSD to test it, thanks

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean you should answer no to any of fsck's questions, just that letting fsck fix things may result in lost data. For instance, blocks that are marked as allocated but are not in any inode's block list will be put on the free block list and potentially overwritten if you resume using the filesystem after it gets fixed. I've reconstructed (admittedly small) text files whose inodes were obliterated by grepping the disk device for known strings, then  using `dd` to copy 8KB blocks in their vicinity, then stitching them together.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had no luck.
I reproduced the problem and couldn't do much with it.
In the end, I just recreated the data previously lost with part of backup